# how to calculate the time keydown to keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is the code, but it's not work,where is wrong.

`<input type="text" name ="name" place="">
    <button disabled="disabled">click</button>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var i = 0;
            $('input').keydown(function(event) {
                i++;
                var temp = i;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var rate = (i-temp);
                    console.log(rate);
                    if(rate--){
                        $('button').attr('disabled',true);
                    }else{
                        $('button').attr('disabled',false); 
                    }
                },1000)
            });
        });`

thx so much  for you guys help

Comment: Have you tried this ?

Comment: Yeah,but the thing is i wanna know the users press the keyboard's rate,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate time between keydown and keyup:

```js
timebetween = 0;
var count = null;
$("input").keydown(function(){ 
    timebetween = 0;
    count = setInterval(function(){
        timebetween++;
    }, 1);
});

$("input").keyup(function(){ 
    clearInterval(count);
    $("body").append("<br>Time between keydown and keyup is "+timebetween+"ms");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript storage which is similar to session variables:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.onkeydown=(function (event) {
            if (localStorage["Count"] == null) {
                localStorage["Count"] = 0;
            }
            else {
                localStorage["Count"]++;
            }

            alert("The count is: " + localStorage["Count"]);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in jquery you can use the following code :

KeyDown :

```
$("input").keydown(function(){ // when user push the key
// do something !!
});
```

KeyUp :

```
$("input").keyup(function(){ // when user is not pushing key enymore
// do something !!
});
```

Comment: OKay,Thx dude, but the thing is i wanna know the users press the keyboard's rate,

Comment: what is keyboard rate  ? do you mean the keys on the keyboard ??

Comment: In other words, how to  calculate the time keydown to keyup

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it will give you time in miliseconds.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var startTime = false, endTime;
   $(window).keypress(function(){ 
    if(!startTime){
      startTime = $.now();
    }
   });

   $(window).keyup(function(){ 
      endTime = $.now();
      var keyPressedTime = (endTime - startTime);
      console.info('keyyyUpppp', keyPressedTime)
      startTime = false;
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Js Project</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="txt" />

<div id="label"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var time = 0; // pressing time
var pressed = 0; // key is pushed or not ?

var timer = setInterval(calculate, 10); // calculate time

$("#txt").keydown(function(){
pressed = 1;
});

$("#txt").keyup(function(){
pressed = 0;
$("#label").html("Pressing Time : "+time+" ms");
time = 0
});

function calculate() { // increase pressing time if key is pressed !!
    if (pressed == 1) {
        time += 1;
    }
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```